# (PILLOW Library) Saving and loading image gives a slighty different array. Bug or feature?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Saving:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(img) #img is a numpy array
im.save("./your_file.jpg")
```

Loading:

```
img2 = Image.open("./your_file.jpg")
img2 = np.array(img2)
```

Checking:

```
img2 == img
```

The results are that there are like 50% False. On inspection, the values are very close. Plotting both `img` and `img2` basically looks the same (at least to my eye), but I am just posting this question up as I am wondering whether is this a bug or a feature in the PILLOW library?

Add-on: Loading with open-cv also gives a different array.

Comment: JPEG is a lossy format (https://stackoverflow.com/q/25153389/9987623), so you don't get the same information you saved to that format.

Comment: Consider using PNG format if you want it lossless.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for the help! You are right, tried PNG and it loaded the same.